# Htaccess поддомен ведет к папке на уровень выше

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, поддомены

Приветствую!
Кто знает, что нужно сделать, чтобы при запросе `sub.domain.com` сайт вел не в папку `/sub`, а например, `sub2/sub`.
Соответственно, чтобы при запросе
`sub.domain.com/1/2/3/file.php` выполнялся
`domain.com/sub2/sub/1/2/3/file.php`. 
Моя конструкция не срабатывает, все ровно ведет в свою директорию:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?^([sub0-9]+)\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(.*)/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub2/$1
```

Comment: @Cript, я удалил свой ответ, поскольку у меня нет возможности протестировать на живом примере ту конфигурацию, которую я в нем указал. Моих знаний не хватает, чтобы предположить причину возникновения ошибки.